# I want to search in any section of the name in column use textbox

Tags: c#

I use this code

```
private void Autocomplete1()
{
        try
        {

            con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn);
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT k1 FROM ork ", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds, "k1");

            AutoCompleteStringCollection col = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            int i = 0;

            for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                col.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["k1"].ToString());
            }

            textBox7.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            textBox7.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col;
            textBox7.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;

            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
}
```

I want to search in any section of the name in column use textbox7

Comment: Are you trying this for multiple column search? Does the above code work or any issue?

Comment: i use one column to search ...but i want search like %mahmoud%

Comment: You can use `WHERE` clause to do the search in the query `LIKE %mahmoud%`.

Comment: done who to use by this code above

Comment: I am not sure what you are writing. I guess, you aren't getting how to use `LIKE %mahmoud%`. Just make it clear.

Comment: sorry how to use by this code above??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131124/discussion-between-mahmoud-magdy-mousaa-and-at-2016).

Comment: no not work i use SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT k1 FROM ork where k1 like'%" + textBox7.Text + "%' ", con);

Comment: It seems like you didn't pass the parameter properly for **TextBox7**. Try to debug and check.

Comment: how ???????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I WANT TO TYPE >>>>say word London >>>TYPE L >>the word London appear <<

when type (o )or (n ) not appear

HOW TO UPDATE these code to do these

```
private void Autocomplete1()
    {
            try
            {

                con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn);
                con.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT k1 FROM ork ", con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(ds, "k1");

                AutoCompleteStringCollection col = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
                int i = 0;

                for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    col.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["k1"].ToString());
                }

                textBox7.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                textBox7.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col;
                textBox7.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;

                con.Close();
            }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void LoadData()
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa; Password =password123;"))
            {
                con.Open();
                AutoCompleteStringCollection citycollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
                string Qry = "select * from Cities";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Qry, con);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        citycollection.Add(dr["Name"].ToString());
                    }

                }
                textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append;
                textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = citycollection;
            }
        }
```

Comment: done this code load data when write >>>>say word London  >>>write L >>the word London appear <<<but when type (o )or (n ) not appear

Comment: textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend; change this line and try

Comment: can u share screenshot

Comment: Please verify this liknk : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/deepak.sharma00/autosuggest-textbox-from-database-column-in-windows-forms/